# Place N number of points having height and width in the sector area of radii of the two concentric circles with radius r1 and r2

Tags: python, python-3.x

How to uniformly pick `N` random points having height and width in the sector area between the two concentric circles with radius `r1` and `r2`

In given image i want to place 5 points inside the blue area:

[image]

place it evenly like this :

[image]

using python code , assume that i have made circles and we have radius `r1` and `r2` and sector angle

Answer (score 0):

You can use math.

Assuming t1 the angle between the vertical and the first radius and t2 the angle you want. Pick a random number between t1 and t2, and the square of a random number between `r1**2` and `r2**2` as the density increases with the square of the distance:

```
import numpy as np

N = 5
tx = np.random.uniform(t1, t2, size=N)
rx = np.sqrt(np.random.uniform(r1**2, r2**2, size=N))
```

Full code to produce a plot:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

N = 10000               # number of points to pick

r1 = 1                  # first radius
r2 = 2                  # second radius

t1 = np.deg2rad(45)     # angle to vertical (arbitrary)
t2 = t1+np.deg2rad(40)  # t1 + 40°

ax = plt.subplot()
ax.set_aspect('equal', adjustable='box')
ax.set_xlim(-r2*1.1, r2*1.1)
ax.set_ylim(-r2*1.1, r2*1.1)

ax.add_patch(plt.Circle((0, 0), r1, edgecolor='k', facecolor='none'))
ax.add_patch(plt.Circle((0, 0), r2, edgecolor='k', facecolor='none'))

ax.plot([0, 0], [0, r2], color='k', ls=':') # vertical

x1, y1  = r2 * np.sin(t1), r2 * np.cos(t1)
x2, y2  = r2 * np.sin(t2), r2 * np.cos(t2)
ax.plot([0, x1], [0, y1], color='k')
ax.plot([0, x2], [0, y2], color='k')

tx = np.random.uniform(t1, t2, size=N)
rx = np.sqrt(np.random.uniform(r1**2, r2**2, size=N))

ax.scatter(rx * np.sin(tx), rx * np.cos(tx), marker='.', s=1, c='k', alpha=0.1)
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: +1 for the square of the radius. It is a common error to just uniformly distribute elements over the radius, and these thus are more shallow then as the radius increases.

Comment: this good , but not match to what  i expected ,t places randomly inside area of shaded part , i want to place uniformly inside the sector shaded area and it dosen't cosider height and width of point

Comment: @vivek I see, then the exact logic and generalization is unclear. What should be the output for 4 points? 100 points?

Comment: @mozway  for 4 points these four point should be plotted in such a way that each is from equal distance and same for 100 points , think like that we have place points in that area like that so no  points gather at one place leaving space nor like randomly , we have to place it like that it looks uniformly placed .

Comment: I'm afraid this description is not sufficient. Please, do provide clear examples with various number of points. Have you tried to do it with pen and paper? This is most likely not straightforward and and clear logic must be explained.

Comment: @mozway , i am not done it with pen and paper  and for some reason i can,t share code here , consider it like what i am doing for 10 images is placing images sequencing which gives me output like [ https://ibb.co/hcsxVzj ] , in which a large space is left , what i want to do for same is  [ https://ibb.co/pvCBFCY ]

Comment: You can [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/77528152/edit) your question to provide your existing code

Comment: @mozway what do you mean by proving more discription bro, i have already given enough and also got same type or exact code from chat gpt bro that you have answered. try to build logic by own bro

Comment: @vivek I don't have enough details to answer, that's it. If you can't provide them, then it's your loss not mine.